# Printf prints wrong value when trying to print the variable alone, prints the right value when printing this variable along with another variable

Tags: c, printf, stdout

I have an embedded board and a camera connected to it. I am trying to print the timestamp from the camera on the console output of the embedded board. The timestamp is accessed and loaded into a structure, and is printed using printf, as follows:

This code is in a loop.

```
f.timestamp = hrt_absolute_time(); // Inbuilt function
printf("Timestamp is %u",f.timestamp);
```

If these lines are run, it always prints "Timestamp is 77". If I do this instead:

```
counter = 1;
f.timestamp = hrt_absolute_time();
printf("The %d st timestamp is %u",counter,f.timestamp);
```

If these lines are run, it prints "The 1 st timestamp is " and the timestamp is updated every second. My question is, how can something so trivial cause such a huge difference? Is it because of the stdout buffer not cleared from some old printf? There are no other print statements in this module. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Entire block:

```
if (msg->msgid == MAVLINK_MSG_ID_OPTICAL_FLOW) {
    mavlink_optical_flow_t flow;
    mavlink_msg_optical_flow_decode(msg, &flow);

    struct optical_flow_s f;

    f.timestamp = hrt_absolute_time();
    f.flow_raw_x = flow.flow_x;
    f.flow_raw_y = flow.flow_y;
    f.flow_comp_x_m = flow.flow_comp_m_x;
    f.flow_comp_y_m = flow.flow_comp_m_y;
    f.ground_distance_m = flow.ground_distance;
    f.quality = flow.quality;
    f.sensor_id = flow.sensor_id;

    printf("Timestamp is %u",f.timestamp);
            //OTHER CODE FOLLOWS
```

Comment: Can we see the whole loop? From this example I don't see anything obviously wrong. Only possibility I see from this is the compiler caching the read value of hrt_absolute_time and never updating it because it's hardware mapped but not marked volatile.

Comment: Maybe you should try with 2 `printf` to see what's happening printf("the %d st", counter); printf(" timestamp is %u", f.timestamp);

Comment: I don't think uit would be a cached value of the timestamp, because the timestamp is in microseconds, so obviously a value much larger than 77. I don't know if the whole loop is that informative though.. I have it in my question now.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of then is possible memory corruption in the `mavlink_msg_optical_flow_decode` or a type mismatch between `timestamp` and the ret value of `hrt_absolute_time`? Just as stumped as you are.

Maybe compiler warnings might give a clue.

Comment: The board has a ground control software in which these values are printed fine. It looks like something that's wrong with the stdout buffer? Not sure what it is yet, but thanks for the inputs.

Comment: Well ideally even if the `stdout` buffer was small it would just cause more flush calls. Maybe try a manual `fflush(stdout)`?

Comment: @Shakti I tried this: The timestamp prints correctly (not 77), but only once: the same value is repeated again and again.

Comment: Just did: the timestamp prints correctly once and the same value is printed again and again, never updated even though we get into the loop at like 10 Hz.

Comment: By same value I assume you mean that `77` and not some other valid value?

Comment: No, sorry, it prints a valid value once and repeats that value again and again.

Comment: It's possible the compiler could have mistakenly moved the `hrt_absolute_time` call outside the loop? Something to look at. Makes me lean towards the memory mapped register not being marked volatile.

Comment: How is `f.timestamp` defined? If it's not of type `unsigned int`, the behavior of your `printf` call is undefined.

Comment: @KeithThompson Scratch that it's `uint64_t`.

Comment: @JesusRamos That could be an issue, yes.. but I am still confused why using two variables in the printf makes it work properly instead of one.

Comment: It could be the way the memory layout in the varargs is changed by the introduction of another variable.

Comment: @HighVoltage: It easily could, depending on how argument values are passed. (And it's easier to fix it than to worry about why it's misbehaving in some particular way.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to information in the comments, `f.timestamp` is of type `uint64_t`.

Unless `uint64_t` is the same type as `unsigned int`, the behavior of

```
printf(" timestamp is %u", f.timestamp);
```

is undefined.

The header `<inttypes.h>` defines format macros for a number of integer types, but I find it easier to cast to a known type:

```
printf(" timestamp is %ju", (uintmax_t)f.timestamp);
```

or

```
printf(" timestamp is %llu", (unsigned long long)f.timestamp);
```

Comment: Casting to long long works! I see my mistake. Can you shed any light on why introducing avnother variable before this caused it to work, even though it was still written as %u?

Comment: @HighVoltage: `printf` was expecting a 32-bit value; you gave it a 64-bit value. The behavior you saw probably has something to do with the way argument values are passed to `printf`, probably on the stack. But frankly it's not worth the effort to track down the details, since you've fixed the problem anyway. (Though this general kind of symptom does tend to imply a format string mismatch, which will be useful knowledge for future debugging.)

Comment: My apologies, I used the wrong format string for `uintmax_t`. `"%zu"` is for `size_t`; `"%ju"` is for `uintmax_t`. I've fixed it now. (Note that this was all introduced in C99; some compilers (*cough*Microsoft*cough*) might not support it.)